# AC-impedance in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I am looking for the Symbol of a AC-impedance as it is used often in some fields of electrical engineering. It's the symbol of a European resistor with a sinusoidal wave in it as in the picture below. Can anyone help me with this?
[image: complex impedance symbol]

Comment: Is this symbol really used? Where have you seen it? Is there a standard which defines it that way? // Never seen it during my last 50 years in electronics here in Germany or elsewhere. What I've seen over and over again, to indicate a complex impedance, is: an ordinary resistor symbol AND using letter Z instead of R ... so it's clear it's not-ohmic, but complex. In very old sources the interior of the resistor was filled with black ink to further emphasize "it's not-ohmic".

Comment: I made a little mistake. I know this sign as a AC-impedance, so I only know this from AC-circuits. I changed this now in the question. At my university this sign is used quite commonly. Normally in connection with power grids.

Comment: Thanks you, @DraUX.

Comment: The symbols is not too difficult to add to `circuitikz` - but I also (like @MS-SPO) never saw it in my (too many) years in the field. If you can find some reference entry for it you can do a component request for it...

Comment: As an electrical engineer, I've never seen this symbol before, regardless of where the source material originates. It's possible I've just not seen anything from wherever you're located, but you may want to consider if you really want to use a symbol that at least seven people so far (myself, MS-SPO, and the five others who upvoted MS-SPO's comment) feel some level of unfamiliarity with.

Comment: Just for the sake of interest, I would like to see some reference, literature of whatever where this is used. Like other comments, for a complex linear impedance (that is consist of R, L and C) we used to use "Z".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to create a custom symbol from scratch, you could use the following code to overlay the last symbol with a small sine wave. Maybe it is sufficient for your needs:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\newcommand{\sine}[1][]{%
 \draw[thick, #1] ++(.8,0) sin ++(.1,.1) cos ++(.1,-.1) sin ++(.1,-.1) cos ++(.1,.1);%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[generic] (2,0);
\sine
\draw (2,0) to[generic] (4,0);

\draw (0,2) to[generic] (0,0);
\sine[rotate=90]
\draw (0,0) to[generic] (0,-2);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, there are 2 (not so compatible to each other) ways: 1. using TikZ's library `circuits.ee.IEC`; and 2. using [`circuitikz` package](https://mirror-hk.koddos.net/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf). Searching the keyword `impedance` from the manuals does not give any result. Do you want to draw it "by hand" with `pic` of TikZ? Note the use of `[sloped]` when the path is not a horizontal line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
% inductor 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{inductor/.pic={
\draw[white,line width=1mm] (-.5,0)--(.5,0);
\draw[decorate,decoration={coil,aspect=0.4,segment length=1mm,amplitude=1.5mm}] (-.5,0)--(.5,0);
}}  

% resistor
\tikzset{resistor/.pic={
\fill[white] (-.5,-.1) rectangle (.5,.1);       
\draw[pic actions] (-.5,-.1) rectangle (.5,.1);
}}

% AC-impedance
\tikzset{AC-impedance/.pic={
\fill[white] (-.5,-.15) rectangle (.5,.15);     
\draw[pic actions] (-.5,-.15) rectangle (.5,.15)
(-.25,0) sin (-.125,.075) cos (0,0) sin (.125,-.075) cos (.25,0); % sin path
}}

% capacitor
\tikzset{capacitor/.pic={
\fill[white] (-.5mm,-2mm) rectangle (.5mm,2mm);
\draw[pic actions] (-.5mm,2mm)--(-.5mm,-2mm) (.5mm,2mm)--(.5mm,-2mm);
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={midway}]
\draw 
(0,2) to pic[sloped,blue]{AC-impedance}
         node[left=1mm]{$Z_1$}
(0,0) to pic{AC-impedance}
         node[above=1mm]{$Z$}
(2,0) to pic{resistor}
         node[above=1mm]{$R$}
(4,0) to pic{inductor} 
         node[above=1mm]{$L$}
(6,0) to pic{capacitor} 
         node[above=1mm]{$C$} (8,0);

\draw (-135:2) to 
pic[sloped,red]{AC-impedance}
node[above=1mm,sloped]{$Z_2$}
(0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also another package, after `circuitikz`, for drawing the circuits: `pst-circ`. Here a small example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\usepackage{amssymb,scalerel}
\newcommand{\sinus}{\hstretch{1.8}{$\boldsymbol\sim$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
\pnode(0,0){A}\pnode(3,0){B}
\pnode(0,2){C}\pnode(3,2){D}
\resistor[labeloffset=0](C)(D){$\sinus$}
\wire(A)(C)
\wire(A)(B)
\wire(B)(D)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]